# Error on "npm install & bower install"

Tags: npm, jhipster

After installation, the new jhipster project appeared here such error:
[image]

it is log file npm-debug.log:

```
1891 verbose stack     at Request.emit (events.js:185:7)
1891 verbose stack     at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:1082:10)
1891 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:95:20)
1891 verbose stack     at Request.emit (events.js:182:7)
1891 verbose stack     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:1009:12)
1892 verbose cwd D:\projects\jproject
1893 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
1894 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
1895 error node v5.5.0
1896 error npm  v3.3.12
1897 error Unexpected end of input
1897 error {"_id":"karma","_rev":"632-143ecb8b5235e3c97cf3d4b359599b72","name":"karma","description":"Spectacular Test Runner for JavaScript.","dist-tags":{"latest":"0.13.19"},"versions":{"0.8.0":{"name":"karma","description":"Spectacular Test Runner for JavaScript.","homepage":"http://karma-runner.github.com/","bugs":{"url":"https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues"},"keywords":["karma","spectacular","runner","testacular","js","javascript","testing","test","...
.8.4"},"peerDependencies":{"karma-jasmine":"*","karma-requirejs":"*","karma-coffee-preprocessor":"*","karma-html2js-preprocessor":"*","karma-chrome-launcher":"*","karma-firefox-launcher":"*","karma-phantomjs-launcher":"*","karma-script-launcher":"*"},"devDependencies":{"grunt":"~0.4","grunt-simple-mocha":"git://github.com/yaymukund/grunt-simple-mocha.git","grunt-contrib-jshint":"~0.3","grunt-coffeelint":"~0.0.6","grunt-npm":"~0.0.1","grunt-bump":"~0.0.
1898 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
1898 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
1899 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Help me why this error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

As written in the [documentation](http://jhipster.github.io/installation/), you must install Grunt before installing JHipster.

If you don't know how to do this, we also provide a Vagrant box where it's already installed.

Comment: At first I have installed yo, bower, grunt-cli, jhipster. Then passes the project folder and there wrote command "yo jhipster" . With each project individually needed install yo, bower, grunt-cli, jhipster?

Comment: I have was individually for the project installed grunt, and bower:

Comment: D:\projects\jproject>npm install -g bower
  C:\Program Files\nodejs\bower -> C:\Program    Files\nodejs\node_modules\bower\bin\bower
C:\Program Files\nodejs
└── bower@1.7.7  "

Comment: I have set Maven ,  the module Spring added, bower.json file showed, configuration database checked, did clean-install and has launched a project with the of spring-boot: run. But the screen browser  does not have a is nothing other than the inscription "This is your footer" ....

Comment: From Grunt-tasks - serve also did. revealed a bug:   Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task
Warning: Error: Cannot find where you keep your Bower packages. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.